# Evaluation Feynman parameters from denominator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I try to evaluate Feynman parameters but got stuck at some point.
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(Ax+(1-x)B)^2}\,dx=\frac{-1}{(Ax+B(1-x))}\frac{1}{A-B}=\frac{1}{AB}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{AB}=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \delta^2(x+y-1) \frac{1}{(Ax+By)^2}\,dx\,dy.
$$
$$
\frac{-\partial}{\partial B}(\frac{1}{AB})=\frac{1}{AB^2}=\int_0^1 \int_0^1\delta^2(x+y-1)\frac{2y}{(Ax+By)^3} \,dx\,dy.
$$
And so on .. Then I can generalize the equation :
$$
\frac{1}{AB^n}=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\delta(x+y-1)n y^{n-1}}{(Ax+By)^{n+1}}\,dx\,dy.
$$
I succeed so far but the next equation is mystery for me. 
$$
\frac{1}{A_1A_2..A_n}=\int \,dx_1 \int \,dx_2 ....\int\,dx_n \frac{(n-1)! \delta^n(x_1+x_2+....x_n-1)}{(A_1x_1+A_2x_2+....+A_nx_n)^n}
$$
How can one obtain the last equation from the previous one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization) shows (what seems like) a full derivation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did not know [Schwinger parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization) That was the trick.

Comment: Personally, I did not know that it had a special name. I thought it was a standard integral identity.